# hard time understanding this code for a numerology program

Tags: java

```
private int sumCharValues (String input) {

    String total = input.toLowerCase();
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = total.length(); i < n; i++) {

        char c = total.charAt(i);
        result += (c - 'a' + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to understand this code. What does the `result += (c - 'a' + 1)` means?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: that's because you can convert a char to its ascii value

Comment: @Leo - Unicode value, actually. :)

Comment: @TedHopp whatever ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `a += b` operator is (more or less—see below) a shortcut for `a = a + (b)`. The expression `(c - 'a' + 1)` converts the character stored in `c` to an integer in such a way that `'a'` will have the value `1`, `'b'` will have the value `2`, etc., based on the Unicode code points of the characters in `input`. When the loop exits, `result` will be the sum of all the numerical equivalents of the characters in the input.

The compound assignment `a += b` isn't *exactly* a shortcut for `a = a + (b)` in a couple of ways. First, the left side is evaluated only once, so something like `vec[i++] += 3` will increment `i` only once. Second, there is an implicit cast (if necessary) to the type of `a`. Thus,

```
byte a = 0;
a += 1; // works
a = a + 1; // compiler error -- a + 1 is an int value
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives the letter's numerical position in the alphabet.

`String total = input.toLowerCase();` means all the letters are lower case. Then, `c - 'a'` subtracts the ascii value for `'a'` from the ascii value of `c`. That means you'll get anything from 0-25. Adding one shifts your starting point, giving you 1-26.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your head or add a print statement in your code for this expression.

When the character in the string is 'a', the expression reads 'a' - 'a' + 1 so you can see that the result will be 1.

When you're performing arithmetic on characters, you're actually doing it on their Unicode value,
For non-accented alphabetic characters, that is the same as ASCII value.

For 'a', this value is 97, for 'b', it's 98, etc.
So the expression above returns the index of the character in the alphabet, starting with 1 for 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `result += (c - 'a' + 1)` is evaluated as,

First char c is converted to its ASCII value, then we get the diff between ascii value of char c and char 'a' and then we add 1 to it.

And this statement `result += (c - 'a' + 1)` can be rewritten as `result = result + (c - 'a' + 1)`, i.e. we are just adding the previous value of result and assigning it again.

PS: The ASCII value of 'a' is 97 and 'z' is 122.

For e.g. if input String is "stackoverflow", it will be evaluated as,

char c = 's', result = 19 
char c = 't', result = 39 
char c = 'a', result = 40 
char c = 'c', result = 43
char c = 'k', result = 54
char c = 'o', result = 69
char c = 'v', result = 91
char c = 'e', result = 96
char c = 'r', result = 114
char c = 'f', result = 120
char c = 'l', result = 132
char c = 'o', result = 147
char c = 'w', result = 170